# inline-block element inside line height element

Tags: html, css

When I need to build up a menu with only one row (mostly one floated to left and one to right) I always used the method of assigning to the parent element a height and a line-height to center vertically all the content, something like this:

```
<div style="height:50px;line-height:50px">
<ul style="float:left">
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
<ul style="float:right">
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
<div>
```

I have always been comfortable with this method, until I had the need to insert an inline-block element inside the line-height element (since I need to define some fixed width elements). The inline-block element, in this case, behaves differently since it take all the height of the line-height element, but I need that it behaves normally allowing me to use width/height property with the same properties of an inline element.

Any solution? I would like to know also if this method of vertical-alignment of one-rows elements is valid or I need to change it due to comodity / compatibility reasons.

```css
div {
  overflow: hidden;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0; margin: 0;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
}

span {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: red;
  width: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div style="background-color:green;height:50px;line-height:50px">
 <ul style="float:left">
  <li>#1</li>
  <li>#2</li>
  <li>#3</li>
 </ul>
 <ul style="float:right">
  <li>#4</li>
    <li><span>#5</span></li>
 </ul>
</div>
<br /><br />
<div style="background-color: green;height:50px;">
 <ul style="float:left">
  <li>#1</li>
  <li>#2</li>
  <li>#3</li>
 </ul>
 <ul style="float:right">
  <li>#4</li>
    <li><span>#5</span></li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then, you will need to assign height to that span elements, which would be the same height as the container.

```
<li><span style="height: 50px;">#5</span></li>
```

But, using flexbox will makes things a lot easier. Example:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: green;
}

.container ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
}

.container li {
  list-style: none;
}

.container span {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul>
    <li>#1</li>
    <li>#2</li>
    <li>#3</li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li>#4</li>
    <li><span>#5</span></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I had heard about this propriety and now I will go to deepen it.